# How to convert a generic method into generic function

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphic-functions

## Question

How to convert the method **timed** into a function?

```
val timing = new StringBuffer
def timed[T](label: String, code: => T): T = {
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
  val result = code
  val stop = System.currentTimeMillis()
  timing.append(s"Processing $label took ${stop - start} ms.\n")
  result
}
```

Below causes "error: not found: type T"

```
val timing = new StringBuffer
val timed: (String, => T) => T = (label, code) => {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val result = code
    val stop = System.currentTimeMillis()
    timing.append(s"Processing $label took ${stop - start} ms.\n")
    result
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as generic function in Scala (and generic value at all), only generic methods are.

Generic functions will appear in Scala 3.

https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/4672

http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/overview.html#new-constructs

```
val timing = new StringBuffer
val timed: [T] => (String, /*=>*/ T) => T = [T] => (label: String, code: /*=>*/ T) => {
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
  val result = code
  val stop = System.currentTimeMillis()
  timing.append(s"Processing $label took ${stop - start} ms.\n")
  result
}
```

in Dotty 0.20.0-RC1.

Answer (score 3):

Scala doesn't have polymorphic functions.

Let me use an example from an [excellent blog post](https://milessabin.com/blog/2012/04/27/shapeless-polymorphic-function-values-1/) by Miles Sabin:

```
def singleton[T](t: T) = Set(t)

// eta-expanded to Int => Set[Int]
List(1, 2, 3) map singleton

// eta-expanded to String => Set[String]
List("foo", "bar", "baz") map singleton
```

Method `singleton()` gets [eta-expanded](https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/on-method-invocations-or-what-exactly-is-eta-expansion-1019b37e010c) into a function at the point of usage, and at that point its types are fixed into inferred concrete types. So it can easily "become" (be expanded into) a function `Int => Set[Int]` or `String => Set[String]`, but cannot stay something like `T => Set[T]`. There's no built-in way of expressing polymorphic functions in the language itself (Scala 3 [might change that](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/4672)).

However, there is a way to have polymorphic functions via natural transformations and/or [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)'s `Poly` with a bit of type gymnastics. Both are based on the same principle of encoding the function as a trait with higher kinded types for input/output and having a generic `apply[T]()` method with an independent type `T` which is fixed to a different concrete type every time the function is invoked (in our case those would be `Int`, `String` etc.).

Something like this:

```
trait PolymorphicFunction[F[_], G[_]] {
  def apply[T](f: F[T]): G[T]
}
```

But instead of attempting to explain it in details here, I would rather refer you to shapeless [documentation](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values) and the aforementioned short series of blog posts.